# PyInstaller with multiple python files

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I would like to make a program `x.py` into an executable(.exe) with `Pyinstaller`. I am able to do this just fine when `x.py` does not depend on any user scripts with:

```
python pyinstaller.py -w x.py
```

How can I make this work when I am importing another script I have written, `y.py`, into `x.py`? I have tried using `-p DIR` to specify the path to `y.py` like so:

```
 python pyinstaller.py -p \projectfolder -w x.py
```

But that did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by having the files in the same directory.  My issue actually turned out to be with a known [bug](http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/596) in pyinstaller with scipy.  The solution to this was adding this import:

```
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import _validation
```

Comment: Can you explain specifically how you got this working i.e.where did you include the imported scripts and what options did you use with pyinstaller?